# Interpret to a complex plane!

Tags: complex-numbers

$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$The question is:

Interpret
$$
\Re z + \Im z = 1
$$
geometrically in the complex plane.

Writing $z = x + yi$, the condition $\Re z + \Im z = 1$ becomes
$x + y = 1$.

Now should we rearrange $y = 1 - x$ and say it is a line that crosses the two coordinates $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$? Or am I way off on this one? :/

Comment: You showed your effort so far: this is a great habit for posting on this forum.

Comment: Thank you @ncmathsadist, Am all about the learning and understand the principals :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are spot-on. This is simply the line in the plane $x + y = 1$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you :)